# Push Notification abrindo nova copia do aplicativo?

Tags: android

Estou tentando criar um push notification porem o push sempre abre uma copia do aplicativo e eu quero que ele abra o meu aplicativo novamente caso esteja em background. Como fazer isso ?

Estou tentando assim

```
public class SendNotification {

    public SendNotification(Context context, String title, String tickerText, String message, String url) {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent contentIntent;

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SplashView.class);

        Bundle bd = new Bundle();
        bd.putString("url", url);
        intent.putExtras(bd);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
                       );

        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setTicker(tickerText)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setShowWhen(true)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentText(message);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);


        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.vibrate = new long[]{150, 300, 150, 600};
        mNotificationManager.notify(AndroidSystemUtil.randInt(), notification);

    }
}
```

Comment: @ramaral e como eu faço para fechar o task atual e reabri-lo como se fosse um reload do meu app ? Estou tentando `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. Mas ainda nao tive resultados. obrigado